# How to make website users go through pages in order

Tags: php, html, web

I am working on a simple website that requires users to enter information in order over 3 different pages.  So they need to go from page A to B to C.  How can I stop them from typing in www.example.com/pageB.php, which skips page A?

Also, I'm not even sure what you call pages that must be visited in order, so any suggestions for google search terms on this also appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you're referring to multipage forms. Refer to these: https://www.formget.com/multi-page-form-php/ and http://form.guide/php-form/php-order-form.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store vars in session to check whether the user has visited previous pages.

page1.php

```
<?php
$_SESSION['has_visited_page1'] = true;
....
```

page2.php

```
<?php
if (empty($_SESSION['has_visited_page1'])) {
    exit('You must visit page 1 first');
}
```

If it's a form, you can store in session the field values from previous page.

Answer (score 0):

you can check page refer info if the page refer not your expected then redirect it or show something you wanted

edited1

in PHP, you can try the code in your pages

> var_dump(@$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])

you'll know how to write it.

Comment: Please note that this is not a secure solution. HTTP_REFERER can be easily spoofed.